# Powerapps - using combobox in place of a dropdown data field from a supporting list

Tags: custom-list, powerapp

I want to use a combobox in order to make use of the Icon and Description. I like the "Person" layout, which I have from another list, but I don't know really how to submit the form and also commit the selection of the combobox as the choice of the new item. They are disconnected, and I'm not sure how to.

The form has 4 fields, the other three fields are just default data cards, the last is a choice field, but since I don't want just the text, I wanted the design of the Icon/Title/Description, I changed the data source to another list in which it's "Title" is the same value as the "Choice" column on the main list.

I'm not really well versed in PowerApps and wanted to see if someone can give me direction.

FEEDBACK (main list)-- "Title"(Text), "Comments"(MultiText), "Person"(People), "Category"(Choice)

CATEGORYCHOICES (supporting list) "Title"(same values as the Feedback "Category" choices), "Icon" (Picture link), "Description"

I guess it could be a lookup, but the lookup column doesn't pull into PowerApps as far as I could tell, or didn't know how to make that relation.

Answer (score 0):

If in understand correctly... you want to change control which is bounded to other `datasource` you can achieve it using `Filter` formula all you need is to conditional check in formula via `Rules`

```
Filter(DT2, ID=DT1Control.ID)
```

> Check [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-filter-lookup) for Filter formula official documentation.
>
> Here is an [example](http://ratsubsharewall.blogspot.com/2017/03/develop-powerapps-from-scratch-series2.html).